# Select Case VBA empty cell

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a code below for a select case loop around a set of cells with decimal values that give different results depending on the value of the input cell. I am trying to add a clause so that if one of the input cells is empty the result is also empty.

This is my code :

```
    Sub JEeldepthoutlet()
    Dim score As Double, result As String
   Dim Rng As Range, i As Long

i = 0

With Sheets("Velocity_Depth")
    For Each Rng In .Range("B12:B16")
        score = Rng.Value
        Select Case score
    Case Is >= 0.05
        result = "1"
    Case Is >= 0.031
        result = "0.6"
    Case Is >= 0.021
        result = "0.3"
    Case Is >= 0
        result = "0"
        End Select
        .Range("Q31").Offset(i).Value = result
        i = i + 1
    Next Rng
End With
End Sub
```

I've tried to add the two following options, neither of which worked :

```
Case Else
result ""
```

This just gave me a result of 0 if there was an empty cell

I also tried

```
Case "" 
Exit Sub
```

This also gave me a result of 0.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a **Variant**:

```
Sub JEeldepthoutlet()
    Dim score As Variant, result As String
    Dim Rng As Range, i As Long

    i = 0

    With Sheets("Velocity_Depth")
        For Each Rng In .Range("B12:B16")
            score = Rng.Value
                Select Case score
                    Case Is = ""
                        result = ""
                    Case Is >= 0.05
                        result = "1"
                    Case Is >= 0.031
                        result = "0.6"
                    Case Is >= 0.021
                        result = "0.3"
                    Case Is >= 0
                        result = "0"
                End Select
            .Range("Q31").Offset(i).Value = result
            i = i + 1
        Next Rng
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the whole Select case in an If statement:

```
Sub JEeldepthoutlet()
Dim score As Double, result As String
Dim Rng As Range, i As Long

i = 0

With Sheets("Velocity_Depth")
    For Each Rng In .Range("B12:B16")
        score = Rng.Value
        If score <> "" Then
            Select Case score
                Case Is >= 0.05
                    result = "1"
                Case Is >= 0.031
                    result = "0.6"
                Case Is >= 0.021
                    result = "0.3"
                Case Is >= 0
                    result = "0"
            End Select
        Else
            result = ""
        End If
        .Range("Q31").Offset(i).Value = result
        i = i + 1
    Next Rng
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It comes up with a Type Mismatch error when I do that, but I changed the score to "Variant" and it worked perfectly. Thank you for your help Scott, I am trying to teach myself VBA for this work project.

Comment: @Lilou Give the correct answer to Gary'sStudent and use his.

Answer (score 0):

When you save an empty cell into a numerical variable it is stored as 0.

To avoid that I've added an if statement before the Select Case

For empty cell I've assigned a value outside the range I used in the case statement in all other cases I assigned the value of the cell.  See below:

```
If ActiveCell = "" Then

    score = 101

Else

    score = ActiveCell

End If

Select Case score

     Case 0 To 35
        Mark = "F"
        Comment = "Terrible - needs attention"
    Case 36 To 50
        Mark = "D"
        Comment = "Needs attention"
    Case 51 To 65
        Mark = "C"
        Comment = "Not bad, could do better"
     Case 66 To 85
        Mark = "B"
        Comment = "Good score"
    Case 86 To 100
        Mark = "A"
        Comment = "EXcelent score - well done!"
    Case Else
        Mark = ""
        Comment = "NO SCORE RECORDED"

End Select
```